# Laravel 4 - using queue for email but not receiving

Tags: php, laravel, email, amazon-sqs, beanstalkd

I currently use AWS SQS to queue my email sending work. I've successfully got it installed, but got a problem with deliverability.

The problem is, the web app does send queue messages to those service successfully, but the messages themselves were not actually delivered into anybody email address. Seems like they stay in the queue forever.

I was just wondering what's causing this?

```
 $email = Input::get('email');

 Mail::queue('emails.changepass', $data, function($message) use ($email)
 {
      $message->to($email)->subject('Change password');
 });
```

I use Gmail SMTP to send out email, it works fine for Mail::send but not Mail::queue.

BTW - there's no error as I've checked the log file.

Comment: Have you checked your log files? They are usually stored in `/app/storage/logs`.

Comment: The error is `[2014-10-13 05:50:51] log.ERROR: exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.' in /home/guusebump/public_html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php:352`. What do you think it is?

Comment: Weird, even if I fixed that error, the problem still persists...

Comment: Are you actually running a `queue:listen` to have Laravel process the queues?

Comment: Just for clarification are you using an Elastic Beanstalk Worker tier environment?

Comment: No I'm not, the Beanstalkd I mentioned is the queue processor, just like AWS SQS.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange for Mail::queue, do I need to do that?

Comment: Yes - you must be running a queue listener, so that anything on the queue is actually processed, including Mail

Comment: I use PuTTy to ssh into the server, in this case how do I make sure the listener command will run forever as long as the app operates? Would it work if I turn off the terminal?